# Using variable to control an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a footer popup that shows when the page is scrolled a certain amount. I have a little `x` that the user can click to make the footer go away. I am trying to use a variable to make the footer stay hidden when the `x` is clicked. I am not able to get it to work like I want and I want to understand why. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var position = $(this).scrollTop();
        var fired = 0;

        if(position < 360 && fired === 0){
            $('#popup').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#popup').slideDown();
        }

        $('.close').on('click', function(){
            $('#popup').slideUp();
            fired = 1; // I thought that this was suppose to override the current variable
        });
    });

});
```

So, why does this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you declared `var fired = 0;` inside the scroll function. So whenever the user scrolls, fired is set to 0.  Just declare it above the scroll-function, then it should work.

Comment: YES!! That makes perfect sense. Thank you!I will mark it as the answer once I can (I have to wait 12 minutes....)

Answer (score 0):

Fired is a local variable to the scroll callback and as a result is always 0. Place it outside of the callback and it will remain once set.

```
jQuery(function($) {
 var fired = 0;
 $(document).scroll(function(){
    var position = $(this).scrollTop();
 //...
```